# New to mining: Am I doing it right?

Tags: mining, wallets

I would like some affirmation that I'm mining correctly. Please take a look:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlWwS.jpg)

I want to solo mine, to me it seems to be working? What does it mean by "solution found"? Did I find a block result?

I appreciate any input.